# What encoding/encryption method is this? A series of 4-digit numbers

Tags: encryption, encoding, radix

Yes I'm doing a CTF, but don't worry I'm not going to get first place either way. Just trying to figure out this problem that's been driving me nuts. Here is the coded text:

```
1143 4423 1553 5321 3111 2253 5344 2311 4414 5215 3131 4324 3344 2315 2315 1142 4434 2115 5115 4254 3211 3300
```

I know it's not ASCII, hexadecimal, or octal, or anything like SHA1 or MD5. From the looks of it, only digits 0-5 are used, so it could be base6?

Is it base 6, and if so, how does one convert this to text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is senary base (known as base 6, heximal or seximal). See [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senary).

Comment: thanks... how would I go about converting this to text?